# TextBlock rendering settings in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am using a TextBlock style.But it looks bad.
Am I missing code may have been written?
How can I solve this problem?

Here is code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">       
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF353535"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextHintingMode" Value="Fixed"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal"/>       
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: What does "it looks bad" mean? What is your problem exactly? Please add some details on what you're trying to achieve and why exactly do you think it's "bad"

Comment: I couldn't add pictures.But in some letters seem pixels.

Answer (score 5):

`TextFormattingMode.Ideal` is far from Ideal :). You should use `Display` for small-to-medium text. More on text formatting [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/21/new-wpf-features-textformattingmode-for-clear-text.aspx).

Here they are compared:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF353535" />
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextHintingMode" Value="Fixed" />
            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma" />
        </Style>


    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBlock>This text has TextOptions.TextRendering mode set to Display</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal">This text has TextOptions.TextRendering mode set to Ideal</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: TextFormatting options comparison]